# My keras neural network predicts the same straight line for both train and test data

Tags: neural-network, keras

I have a neural network as below:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 36)                288       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 37        
=================================================================
Total params: 325
Trainable params: 325
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The activation functions for the first and second layers are "relu" and "sigmoid" respectively.
My problem is the output is a straight line:

[image]

I did more investigation and figured out that the weights of this neural net are also a straight line (just first layer).
x_train shape is (2516, 7), and y_train shape is (280, 7)

one of the features (dimensions) of the input data is like below and other are similar to this:

[image]

and the labels are like below:

[image]

Comment: There are many things that can go wrong, I see that your features have a very small range, so a start would be to normalize them to the range[0, 1] or [-1, 1]. Then training a neural network is not just a matter of feeding the data in, the loss and activations have to be appropriate. What exact problem are you trying to solve? (regression/classification?)

Comment: I bet the problem is "relu" :p

Comment: @Daniel Möller I changed it to sigmoid, now I do not get constant weights through epochs but the prediction is still a straight line.

Comment: @ Matias Valdenegro, I normalized the inputs to the range [0, 1] and I no longer get a straight line for prediction. my problem is a regression.